# Proof regarding rewriting an infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Prove that if an infinite set can be written as a finite disjoint union of subsets, then one of the subsets will necessarily have infinitely  many elements.

So it's basically a pigeonhole problem. I am sure that the statement is true but I am not sure how to prove it

Comment: Do you know that finite unions of finite sets are finite?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $A$ is an infinite set. Suppose that we could write $A=\bigcup_{i=1}^nB_i$ for a certain $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and finite sets $B_i$. Clearly $\sum_{i=1}^n|B_i|\geq |A|$ but this is a contradiction since the left-hand side is finite and the right-hand side is infinite. Thus we conclude by contradiction.

Comment: @LeBtz: Thanks for correcting the typo.